# Ubuntu 13.04 installation no response

Tags: usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 into my USB with universal usb installer. When I plug it into my Macbook Pro retina 13 2012 edition, rebooted it and pressed ALT to select to boot from my USB, it gets into it and lets me select "try" or "install ubuntu". So I selected install, but when i got in it just shows the wallpaper and a mouse, and nothing else, so I can't install it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install ubuntu by the following steps:

Make sure you have allocated free space, if it still can`t boot to installation GUI, try to run ubuntu installer in text mode.

### 1. First,create a Partition

The first step is pretty simple.  You can resize the Macintosh partition using the OSX Disk Utility.  I resized the partition to 90GB and left the rest as free space.

### 2. Create USB Installer

You should [follow the directions to create a 64-bit Ubuntu USB startup drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).
At the end of the instructions, you’ll see an error message indicating that OSX isn’t able to read the drive.

**Don’t worry, this is normal and it should still work as a USB installer but you just won’t be able to read/write to the drive itself.**

#### (OPTIONAL but RECOMMENDED)

Since you won’t be able to read/write to this drive, if you have another USB stick handy, you should upload the wifi driver to the 2nd USB stick.  After the Ubuntu installation, wifi will not work and you will need to install the driver and its 3 dependencies to get it working.

### 3. Install Boot Manager

I used rEFInd as the boot manager instead of rEFIt.  It seems to work for me.  [Download the binary zip file](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).  Once downloaded and unzipped, open a Terminal window and install:

```
cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.6.7  
 ./install.sh
```

### 4. Install Ubuntu

Here comes the fun part.
Insert your Ubuntu USB installer and restart your computer.  When the computer restarts, you should see your new boot manager screen with an Apple and a triangle shaped icon for the Ubuntu installer.  Right arrow over to the installer and hit Enter to select it.  This will load the typical Ubuntu installer.  Select “Install Ubuntu”.  If this is the first time you are installing Ubuntu, it should give you the option to install Ubuntu alongside Mac OSX.  If you are reinstalling over a bad installation, it will give you the option to erase Ubuntu only and reinstall.  WARNING! If you are attempting a reinstall and select this option, the previous swap partition will not be reused or erased.  A new one will be created meaning you will lose about 8GBs of space for nothing.  Instead of having the installer create the partitions for you, initial install or reinstall, I recommend selecting the “Something else” option and create your own partitions.

If you select “Something else” you will see a screen with a list of partitions.  If this is a reinstall, scroll to the bottom of the list and delete the previous install’s partitions.  At the very bottom of the list is “Free space”.  Select that and click on the “+” sign to create a new partition.  You can create a root “/” using ext4 with a size of about 25GB.  Next, create a swap partition with a size around 8 to 16GB.  Finally, create an ext4 home “/home” partition with the rest of the remaining space and continue with the installation.  After the installation, it will ask you to reboot and you should do so.  If you get a blank screen after the message, just hit the space bar and it will continue.